# TCL script to replace C file line

Tags: tcl

I have  C file at

> C:\SVN\Code\fileio.c

This reads 2 audio files as

```
tuningFile = fopen("../../simulation/micdata.bin", "rb");   
mic1File = fopen("../../simulation/mic1.pcm", "rb");
```

I need to write TCL script code that will read the C file, and replace these 2 occurrences to

```
tuningFile = fopen("C:/SVN/simulation/micdata.bin", "rb");    
mic1File = fopen("C:/SVN/simulation/mic1.pcm", "rb");
```

Can anyone give a compact example for something like below:

- read file line wise
- search  for something like *tuningFile = fopen(*
- extracting path from it and change it to absolute path
- combine it with *tuningFile = fopen(
- replace original line with modified line at same location

Thanks
sedy

Comment: You better have to create a temporary file with correction and replace the actual file with temporary file.

Comment: I can't do that. The TCL script is passed an argument which decides whether to keep absolute or relative paths.So, I need a way to change it programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

The key is that you actually want to replace:

```
fopen("../../simulation/
```

with

```
fopen("C:/SVN/simulation/
```

That's easily done with `string map`. The rest of your problem is then just a matter of doing the file I/O, and pretty much *any* C source file that can be compiled by an ordinary compiler is best processed by loading it all into memory at once:

```
set filename {C:\SVN\Code\fileio.c}
set mapping [list {fopen("../../simulation/} {fopen("C:/SVN/simulation/}]

# Slurp the file in
set f [open $filename]
set data [read $f]
close $f

# Apply the mapping
set data [string map $mapping $data]

# Make the original a backup
file rename $filename $filename.bak

# Write back with a separate open
set f [open $filename w]
puts -nonewline $f $data
close $f
```

If you prefer, you can get the filename as an argument using, say, `[lindex $argv 0]`. The rest of the code doesn't care.

Comment: I appreciate the response. However, the mapping from relative to absolute path is not fixed per se. So, if the script runs on different machine, _"../../simulation/_ might translate to something else , and not _"C:/SVN/simulation"_. So, I need _[file normalize $origfile]_ to be used so that once line is read with relative path, it replaces it with absolute path obtained through _[file normalize $origfile]_.

Answer (score 1):

```
package require fileutil

set filename C:/SVN/Code/fileio.c
set mapping [list {fopen("../../simulation/} {fopen("C:/SVN/simulation/}]

proc replace {mapping data} {
    string map $mapping $data
}

::fileutil::updateInPlace $filename [list replace $mapping]
```

Should work too. (Definition of `mapping` nicked from Donal.) `updateInPlace` calls the command prefix in its second argument, passes the contents of the file to that command, and updates the file with the result from the command.

This is very nearly the same procedure as in Donal's answer, expressed in higher-level code. If you want a backup copy, do this before calling `updateInPlace`:

```
file copy $filename [file rootname $filename].bak
```

Documentation: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that extracts the filename and uses `file normalize` on it:

```
set f [open $filename r]
set code [read $f]
close $f

set code [subst -novar -noback [regsub -all {((?:tuningFile|mic1File) = fopen\(")([^"]+)} $code {\1[file normalize "\2"]}]]
```

Breaking that up,

1. this command

   ```
   regsub -all {((?:tuningFile|mic1File) = fopen\(")([^"]+)} $code {\1[file normalize "\2"]}
   ```

   will find the string `tuningFile = fopen("../relative/file` (or "mic1file = ...") and replace it with the text

   ```
   tuningFile = fopen("[file normalize "../relative/file"]
   ```
2. Then we feed that to `subst` so that embedded commands can be substituted,  executing that `file normalize` command, resulting in the text

   ```
   tuningFile = fopen("/full/path/to/file
   ```

---

Take 2: handle brackets in C code

```
$ pwd
/home/jackman/tmp/base/SVN/Code

$ tree ../..
../..
├── SVN
│   └── Code
│       ├── fileio.c
│       └── normalize.tcl
└── simulation
    ├── mic1.pcm
    └── micdata.bin

3 directories, 4 files

$ cat fileio.c 
int tuningFix[MAXTUNING];
tuningFile = fopen("../../simulation/micdata.bin", "rb");   
mic1File = fopen("../../simulation/mic1.pcm", "rb");

$ cat normalize.tcl 
#! tclsh
package require fileutil
set code [fileutil::cat [lindex $argv 0]]

# protect existing brackets
set bracketmap [list \[ \x01 \] \x02]
set code [string map $bracketmap $code]

# normalize filenames
set code [
    subst -novar -noback [
        regsub -all {((?:tuningFile|mic1File) = fopen\(")([^"]+)} $code {\1[file normalize "\2"]} 
    ]
]

# restore brackets
set code [string map [lreverse $bracketmap] $code]

puts $code

$ tclsh normalize.tcl fileio.c 
int tuningFix[MAXTUNING];
tuningFile = fopen("/home/jackman/tmp/base/simulation/micdata.bin", "rb");   
mic1File = fopen("/home/jackman/tmp/base/simulation/mic1.pcm", "rb");
```

Comment: This essentially is the Tcl idiom for the perl `s/pattern/some code here/e`

Comment: Hi Glenn, the regsub command fails for me as the C code has array defined as  **int tuningFix[MAXTUNING];**  and interpreter treats it as command when read from $code and complains.

Comment: Added updated version that handles brackets in the code

Answer (score 0):

based on great help from all users who commented, I was able to do the task as

```
proc replaceFileTemp {} {
    global pth_fileio_orig

    # create backup for copy back
    set pth_backup [file rootname $pth_fileio_orig].bak
    file copy $pth_fileio_orig $pth_backup

    #get current file path
    set thisFilePth [ dict get [ info frame [ info frame ] ] file ]

    # get folder for current file
    set thisFileFolderPth [file dirname $thisFilePth]

    # set the replacement string/path
    set replacementPth [file dirname $thisFileFolderPth]


    # obtain original string to be replaced 
    set origPth "../../simulation/toplevel"

    # download package for file manipulation
    package require fileutil


    set mapping [list $origPth $replacementPth]
    proc replace {mapping data} {
    string map $mapping $data
    }

    # replace original string with replacement string for all occurrences in file
    ::fileutil::updateInPlace $pth_fileio_orig [list replace $mapping]
}

# set the path to toplevel C file
set pth_fileio_orig [file normalize "../../../fileio.c"]
replaceFileTemp
```